# Android share ViewModel between fragment and dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, android-dialogfragment, android-viewmodel

How to share same viewModel between dialog and dialogFragment? I know that viewModel can be shared in activity scope. But it is too big scope for me.

```
 private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Unfortunately I don't have in a project navigation component.

Comment: You can check out here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing

Comment: Yeah I exactly used this source. This line in question is even from this page. The problem is that my fragment shows product details and I have multiple products and I need to clean my liveData manually. And I have only one activity, so I don't needed this viewModel all the time. Only when user enters the details page.

Comment: you show dialog and dialogFragment at the same time?

Comment: Yes. I show fragment and over it I show dialog fragment. I run same request to update UI in fragment and dialogFragment.

Comment: and you want to share between fragment and dialogFragment right?

Comment: Yes. Only between them.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219116/discussion-between-kkkkk-and-cong-hi).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Use `childFragmentManager` to show `DialogFragment`
2. Declare shared `ViewModel` inside `Fragment` by

```
private val sharedViewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels()
```

3. Inside `DialogFragment` declare `ViewModel` by

```
private val sharedViewModel: YourViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() })
```

Comment: Really appreciated. Nicely described.

Comment: Is there an updated version where we show it using android navigation?

Comment: @shinta you can use the same `by viewModels` delegate because the navigation component uses the `childFragmentManager` as well.

Comment: what about the opposite case, get viewModel for a fragment that opened by dialoge. 
so i need viewmodel between parent (dialoge), and fragment [child]?

Comment: hmmm this didn't work. app crashes when dialog fragment tries to get the vm